# Accessing Yelp API with iOS using the OAuthConsumer

Tags: ios, api, oauth, hyperlink, yelp

Yelp have a link to an API on their website: http://www.yelp.co.uk/developers/documentation/v2/authentication

I am trying to access it with iOS (using [this](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/ios) API), but I am quite new to OAuth.

Can someone supply some example Objective-C of how to use this API?

The only ones I can find need a 'get request token' URL, and Yelp does not need this as is uses a signature.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but have you looked at their github examples? that should give you some enlightenment https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/ios/YelpAPI

Comment: the author clearly links to that example in the question, please remove

Answer (score 0):

The github example you mention has a test that demonstrates how to query restaurants in New York, which worked for me.

You need to edit `Tests/OAuthTest.m` to supply your OAuth info (i.e. replace the strings `"CONSUMER_KEY"`, `"CONSUMER_SECRET"`, `"TOKEN"`, `"TOKEN_SECRET"` with valid values).

Then you need to make sure you are building the `Tests` target. The default, at least for me, was the `YelpAPI` target.